# Definition of Energy "Capacity to do work"

Tags: forces, energy, work

My school textbook states if a ball falls due to free fall, its weight will do work, which is transferred to Kinetic Energy when dropped from a certain height.

Hence, work done = energy transferred.

But then it says this is as 'energy is defined as the capacity to do work'.

What does the term 'capacity to do work' mean?

I am very confused! How does this relate to the subject of `work done = force x distance moved in direction of the force`?

Also, it says that if a 40N force is applied on a box that is moving on a rough surface at constant speed, the work done on the box is "transferred into *thermal energy* between the box and surface below" - but isn't some of the work done transferred into kinetic energy to keep the box moving?

Comment: "Energy is the capacity to do work " is an extremely bad definition of energy

Comment: @Sherlock That's not the best phrasing but it is essentially the definition that was used from the time the concept was settled until Emmy Noether provided a better one. And it is still the only definition available at the introductory level.

Comment: *"How does this relate to the subject of work done = force x distance moved in direction of the force?"* That is the reason the idea is not as trivial as it sounds. There is, however, nothing built into the two statements that tells you that these ideas together form the basis of a self-consistent framework for useful physical analysis: you have to do the math. Start with Newton's laws and kinematics, define kinetic energy, derive the work energy-theorem, think about conservative forces and use that to bootstrap new energies from the work energy theorem, and posit conservation. Then test.

Comment: @dmckee---ex-moderatorkitten disagree. The phrasing is completely meaningless as it is circular. Noether’s theorem doesn’t need to be used in order to define energy, because the concept of energy was still a thing before Noether’s theorem was proved.

Comment: The description is also incorrect.  An energy gradient is necessary to do work, regardless of the level of the "starting" energy.  In other words, if a large amount of energy was equally distributed everywhere throughout the universe such that the energy level was equally high everywhere, no work could be done by using that energy.

Answer (score 1):

> Also, it says that if a 40N force is applied on a box that is moving on a rough surface at constant speed, the work done on the box is "transferred into thermal energy between the box and surface below" - but isn't some of the work done transferred into kinetic energy to keep the box moving?

The book is wrong. The 40 N force acting on the box is doing work on the box. The friction between the box and the surface below is doing work on the box. The constant speed simply tells you that the total work being done on the box is zero. Something had to get the box moving initially, and once that happens it will moving at constant speed on a straight line (Newton's first law) until something from outside the box acts on the box. In your case, the 40 N does exactly the same work as the friction, but we shouldn't say the work by the 40 N force "is tranferred" to thermal energy. We don't know where the work was transferred. All we know is that the *sum* of work is zero.

One just as easily (and just as falsely) could argue that the friction is stealing some of the initial kinetic energy, and the 40 N force is adding to the kinetic energy. All we know for sure are the total effects, not the pathways.

Comment: The book is not wrong.  The proximal cause of the heating is the work done by friction.  But that thermal energy came from *somewhere*.   At one time it was chemical energy in my muscles.  It ended up as thermal energy.  One of the intermediate steps is that energy transferred from my hand to the box my means of work.  We do consider that heat and work are *transfers* of energy, so I think it's perfectly fine to say that the work done on the box is transfered (by a chain of events) into thermal energy in the surface.

Answer (score -1):

Work done = energy transferred. The word transfer means the energy has moved from 1 body to another. That’s why we say work done **on** a body and **not** work done **by** the body. Let us say you press against a wall. The wall does not move and so you have not been able to transfer energy and so work done is zero but a bulldozer can destroy a wall. So the bulldozer does work **on** the wall. It has more power. Be that as it may.Now to your question How does this relate to the subject of work done = force x distance moved in direction of the force?"

Here is the proof that work is nothing but energy transferred. will use  one of the SUVAT equations of motion which is v^2 = u^2 + 2as where v is the final velocity, u is the initial velocity a = acceleration and s is the distance travelled. Now we know force F= ma. Substituting a = F/m and  Rearranging we get
1/2mv^2 - 1/2mu^2 = F x s which is work done, but 1/2mv^2 - 1/2mu^2 is nothing but the change in Kinetic energy which led to the definition of the work-energy theorem. The definition of the work-energy theorem is
**The net work done by the forces acting on a body is equal to the change in kinetic energy of the body.**

if however there is a freely falling body then F = mg and this equation can be rewritten as
1/2mv^2 - 1/2mu^2 = mg(h2-h1) where s= h2-h1 . So change in kinetic energy = change in gravitational potential energy = F x s which is defined as work done **on** a body.   Now this also proves the concept of  **conservation of energy** which is energy is neither created nor destroyed but can be converted from one form to another. This shows any change in kinetic energy must be equal to the change in potential gravitational energy and vice versa.

The book is partially right. A portion of the 40N force that is applied is indeed converted into heat energy and some into sound and some into balancing the friction and some to balance air resistance. So if all these resistive forces are equal to the 40 N force and if the body was already in uniform motion according to Newton’s first law the body will continue to move at a constant speed (velocity).

That’s why the units of work and energy are one and the same. Hope this clarifies.